# Why are C# callbacks only executed when the python module uses cv.imshow()?

Tags: c#, python, c++, unmanaged, pybind11

I couldn't come up with a better more descriptive title as it involves 3 languages which I'll explain now.
I wrote a `C++` wrapper around a Python module, which works just fine in C++ by the way. I made a DLL out of this wrapper and exposed some functionalities as a C and used them in a C# application.

The issue is, the `C#` application just hangs if I do not display the webcam feed.
That is in `Python` module there is this condition:

```py
if self.debug_show_feed:
    cv2.imshow('service core face Capture', frame)
```

and when set `True`, will display the webcam feed.
This is mostly a debug thing I put and for actual production it needs to be disabled. On C++ its fine 
I can set this to `false` (through the constructor) and all is fine.
However, On `C#`, this behavior doesn't happen, if I try to use the module without setting the webcam feed to `true`, The `C#` app hangs, and that's because the `Start()` which calls the main operation becomes a blocking call and none of the callbacks are returned.
my `DllImport` are as follows by the way:

```cs
[DllImport(@"Core_DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int Initialize(bool showFeed);

[DllImport(@"Core_DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void Start(bool async);

[DllImport(@"Core_DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void Stop();

[DllImport(@"Core_DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void SetCpuAffinity(int mask);



public delegate void CallbackDelegate(bool status, string message);
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]

[DllImport(@"Core_DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void AddCallback(IntPtr fn);

[DllImport(@"Core_DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void RemoveCallback(IntPtr fn);
```

And this is my C# callback:

```cs
private CallbackDelegate del;
public void SetUpCallback()
{
    txtLog.Text += "Registering C# callback...\r\n";
    del = new CallbackDelegate(callback01);
    AddCallback(Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(del));
    txtLog.Text += "Calling passed C++ callback...\r\n";
}

bool status;
string id;
public void callback01(bool status, string id)
{
     this.status = status;
     this.id = id;
}
```

And this is the main python modules that are executed :

```py
def start(self):
    try:
        self.is_running = True
        self._main_loop()

    except Exception as ex:
        path='exceptions-servicecore.log'
        track = traceback.format_exc()
        exception_time = datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
        with open(path, 'a') as f:
            f.writelines(f'\n{exception_time} : exception occured {ex.args} \n{track}')

def start_async(self):
    st = threading.Thread(target=self.start) 
    st.start()

def _main_loop(self):

    name = None
    is_valid = False
    while self.is_running and self.cap.isOpened():
        is_success, frame = self.cap.read()
        if is_success:
            name="sth"
            is_valid=True

            self._execute_callbacks(is_valid, name, frame)
            self._execute_c_callbacks(is_valid, name)

            if self.debug_show_feed:
                cv2.imshow('service core face Capture', frame)

        if self.save:
            self.video_writer.write(frame)

        if (cv2.waitKey(1)&0xFF == ord('q')) or (not self.is_running):
            break

    self.cap.release()
    if self.save:
        self.video_writer.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Knowing this only happens in `C#` and not `C++`, I may have some issues in my marshaling or the way I'm trying to use the `C#` callback in this scenario.

Here is a Visual Studio with a minimal example that demonstrates this: https://workupload.com/file/epsgzmMMVMY

What is the problem here? Why is `cv.imshow()` causes this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason why callbacks on C# side didn't output anything. The callbacks are all executing as they should, but since the main loop on Python side is a blocking method, they only start their execution when the blocking method is over (just like a recursive function where the outputs don't get to be returned until the very end).

I then noticed `cv2.imshow()` creates a short pause and in that time, the `C#` client gets the chance to update the output and what it has been sent to. I first tried to pause the current running thread in Python, and it actually kind of worked, the output started to popup on C# side, but still the app was not responsive.

I noticed I can actually make the callback outputs show up in C# by simply using a `cv2.waitkey(1)` or `cv2.imread('')` in the else clause when `showFeed` is False:

```py
while (self.is_running):
...
    if self.showFeed:
        cv2.imshow("image", frame)
    else:
        #cv2.imread('')
        # or 
        cv2.waitkey(1)
    ...
```

And by writing :

```py
while (self.is_running):
...
    if self.showFeed:
        cv2.imshow("image", frame)
    else:
        cv2.namedWindow('image', cv2.WINDOW_OPENGL)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    ...
```

The outputs are showing just fine and the application is responsive again, However, constantly creating and destroying an empty Opencv window is not a solution as it flickers and is just very bad.

I need to add that, using a timer() control event on c# to print the output and keep the app responsive doesn't work, creating a new thread also doesn't seem to work. it seems the marshaled callbacks this way can't be used like this (I am happy to hear that I am wrong though).

I'll update this answer when I find better solutions than these both C# wise (running the callbacks on a thread) or on Python side, making a visible window or altogether fix this issue.

### Update

I removed the changes on Python side and implemented the threading on C# part. The reason the initial threading didn't work was because, all interops had to be called in the same thread, meaning all of the imported methods such as `Initialize`, `Start` and `AddCallback` had to be setup and run from within the same thread.