# Is it possible to execute C# callbacks to unmanaged function in a thread?

Tags: c#

This is a follow-up question about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61183964/why-are-c-sharp-callbacks-only-executed-when-the-python-module-uses-cv-imshow). Basically I am trying to send C# callback to a Python Module using a C++ wrapper. the issue is, since the main method, is a blocking method (a while loop that keeps dispatching the information to the callbacks. The issue is, it's so fast the C# GUI can't cope with it and thus gets unresponsive.

I tried using a timer `Tick()` event to display the information every second, but it seems the callback exhausts the process so much so that the timer itself can't output. I even tried using a thread to execute the callback, but that fails as well meaning, the application continues to be unresponsive.

My question is, Is there something that I can do to rectify this from C# side? for example can we make the callback somehow run in a separate thread that doesn't make the application unresponsive?

### Update

Here are some more information (taken from the linked question):

My `DllImport` are as follows:

```cs
[DllImport(@"Core_DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int Initialize(bool showFeed);

[DllImport(@"Core_DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void Start(bool async);

[DllImport(@"Core_DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void Stop();

[DllImport(@"Core_DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void SetCpuAffinity(int mask);



public delegate void CallbackDelegate(bool status, string message);
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]

[DllImport(@"Core_DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void AddCallback(IntPtr fn);

[DllImport(@"Core_DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void RemoveCallback(IntPtr fn);
```

And this is my C# callback:

```cs
private CallbackDelegate del;
public void SetUpCallback()
{
    txtLog.Text += "Registering C# callback...\r\n";
    del = new CallbackDelegate(callback01);
    AddCallback(Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(del));
    txtLog.Text += "Calling passed C++ callback...\r\n";
}

bool status;
string id;
public void callback01(bool status, string id)
{
     this.status = status;
     this.id = id;
}
```

Basically, when you call `Start()` the main loop starts, and the callback gets called indirectly.

If I try to run the Start using a thread, I get no more callback output:

```cs
Thread t;
private void btnRunService_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tmrFetchStatus.Start();
    //Start(chkboxAsync.Checked);
    t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
    {
         RunService();
    }));
    t.IsBackground = true;
    t.Start();
}

void RunService()
{
    Start(chkboxAsync.Checked);

    if (txtLog.InvokeRequired)
    {
        txtLog.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(()=>
        {
            txtLog.Text += "OK";  
        }));
    }
    else
    {
        txtLog.Text += "OK"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Well just starting a new thread and calling the interop function in that from C# isn't hard if that's what you need. But I don't quite understand the question so I don't know how to answer.

Comment: That doesnt work. this was the first thing I did. The whole project is given in link given by the way. 
the issue is threading and timer() control dosnt help in making  the application responsive here.

Comment: @Joelius I updated the question with couple of snippets, is this what you had in mind? 
this doesnt work as I pointed out in the question

Comment: If your problem is the UI can't cope with the update speed - in general the solution is not to process through the UI. Only use it for interaction purposes

Comment: The problem is, I cant seem to be able to somehow slow it down! when the start is pressed, the application just gets unresponsive . if I try to run the start method in a separate thread, then the callback wouldnt work. at least I get no output and I dont know how to check if I have anything at all.

Comment: You should probably set up a processing queue instead of trying to interact with the UI in the callback.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks a lot , but the problem is two fold. the start is a blocking call itself. so that alone will make the app unresponsive, if I run `start` with a thread like the way I showed above, the app is responsive obviously, but callback doesnt run at all. as the id and status variables never get updated. 
Thats the confusing part

Comment: @Joelius please have a look at my comment to HansPassant. The issue is not that simple. for that I need either run Start in a separate thread or come up with something else, running start in a separate thread just doesnt run the callbacks it seems.

Comment: Does it work when you register the callbacks on the same thread you call `Start`? I'd expect that you  have to do all the interop calls in the same thread otherwise the callbacks might not work but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Joelius oh my God! that was it. this nearly took my whole day and it didnt even cross my mind. Thanks a lot. really really appreciate it. please post that as asnwer so we can call it day :)

Comment: Done. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, the threading issue was caused because the `Start` method wasn't called on the same thread as the `AddCallback` method.

When working with dependant interop calls (or actually dependant calls in general) it's best to stay on the same thread unless you know it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you again it was really helpful :)